# How to convert the type of pointer

Tags: c

I want to convert the type of the pointer 'p'.  Begining ,the type of the pointer p is void .After allocating four bytes of memory for it, I cast pointer type into 'int',However ,this doesn't work . maybe the sentence `p=(int *)p` doesn't work.
Please tell me why  and solve the problem.thanks.
The coding:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 int main(void)
{
   void *p;
   p=malloc(sizeof(int));
   if(p == NULL)
    {
        perror("fail to malloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    p=(int *)p;
        *p=100;
    printf("the value is : %d\n",*p);

    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have an easier time directly casting the void pointer returned by `malloc` to an `int*`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   int *p;
   p = malloc(sizeof(int));
   if(p == NULL)
    {
        perror("fail to malloc");
        exit(1);
    }

    *p=100;
    printf("the value is : %d\n",*p);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Don't even need to go that far. Just make `p` an `int*` and not a `void*`.

Comment: I know we're dealing with a corner case here, but I wouldn't recommend posting code that casts the return value from `malloc(3)` -- that cast can actually hide helpful warning messages from the compiler.

Comment: [Don't cast the return value from malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/241631)

Comment: could you tell me that the sentence 'p=(int *)p' could works ？

Comment: Sorry I fixed that.  It's a terrible habit I really need to break.

Comment: I'm sorry posting this code.I just begin to study Linux C ,so sometimes there are a lot of questions trouble me.I just want to know it. The last ,Thank you for your help

Comment: you've better to use cast `p = (int*) malloc...`.

Comment: @mattn No, _don't_ cast the result of malloc ever in C.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change a variable's type after you have declared it.  For what you are asking, you need to declare a separate `int*` variable and assign your `p` variable to it with the type-cast:

```
int *i = (int *)p; 
*i = 100; 
printf("the value is : %d\n", *i);
```

Or, simply declare `p` as a `int*` to begin with and then type-cast the pointer returned by `malloc()`, like @GWW showed.

Answer (score 1):

You cant change a variables type, you can do a type cast but that is only temporary.
what you want would be something like `*(int*)p = 100;
printf("the value is : %d\n", *(int*)p);`

Answer (score 1):

You can't. But you can create a new pointer to int and point to that position, like:

```
void *p;
p= malloc...
int *pi;
pi= p;
*pi= 25;
```